# The image doesn't upload

Tags: php

I'm using this piece of code:

```
    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

        if (file_exists("images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        } else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
            "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            echo "Stored in: " . "images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Invalid file";
}
```

However, almost everything works except the upload part. It returns correctly the type, name and the path but it does not upload the file to the server. Yes, I did CHMOD my folder, what could it be?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You have `if (file_exists("images/"` and `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/"` maybe `upload/` should be `images/` 2 different folders would be the fault. Which folder are you wanting to upload to?

Comment: Amazing, I did not find it yet(until now). Thanks. ;)

Comment: I can't see the lines of code where you actually upload the image?

Comment: @Nilzone- move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]... should do the job.

Comment: @JurP I saw it just as I posted the comment, and then couldn't delete it, but thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You have `if (file_exists("images/"`

and `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/"`

`upload/` which should be `images/`